# jQuery ready block hiding code outline in IDE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ide, outline, onready

When I write the following code, whether Im using Aptana, Dreamweaver or Eclipse, I can never see functions in the onready block in the outline view:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function myFunction(){
   }
   function myFunction2(){
   }
});
```

Basically the only thing I see in outline is the onready and I have to remove the onready if I want to see all my functions. What technique or way of handling this situation can I try to both see all the functions in outline view and still use onready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What technique or way of handling this situation can I try to both see
>   all the functions in outline view and still use onready?

Just don't define your own functions inside like you demostrated. It's unnecessary. Have your functions defined outside like so:

```
function myFunction(){

}

function myFunction2(){

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
    myFunction2();    

});
```

Comment: This wont work, I dont want the functions executed, I only want them available.

Comment: I don't think there is a way of doing what you want. The IDEs are just not smart enough. They parse top level functions only, usually.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do the onready is:

```
$(function(){
 ... code here ...
})
```

Maybe this will solve your problem...